# AppleScript Quicktime record on different camera

Tags: applescript

How do I change the quicktime document current camera to a different camera in AppleScript?
I want the script to automatically switch to my iphone and then record a video.

I have it done so that it's using system events clicks but this way is slow and clunky.

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate

    tell application "System Events"
        activate
        tell process "QuickTime Player"


            click menu item "New Movie Recording" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
            set cameras to button 3 of window 1
            click cameras
            delay 0.5
            click menu item 3 of menu 1 of cameras
        end tell
    end tell

    delay 2
    tell (document 0)
        start
        delay 3
        stop
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 4):

As per the *QuickTime Player* scripting library, you can retrieve a list of video recording devices using the command:

```
        get [id, name] of video recording devices
```

which will return something like:

```
        {{"CC26302Z3U5H0X0FP", "iGlasses"}, {"FaceTime Camera", "iGlasses"}}
```

corresponding the id and name of each camera, respectively.  Each movie recording has a bunch of properties, one of which is called **current camera**, which is of type *video recording device*.  This property is both readable and settable, in theory.

Therefore, one ought to be to do this:

```
        set R to new movie recording -- creates new recording
        set current camera of R to video recording device named "iGlasses"
```

However, this command does absolutely nothing.  Indeed, when I try and read the value of the property, using `get current camera of R`, it returns `missing value`.

So, my feeling is that this feature has yet to be implemented properly into AppleScript, or there's a bug in QuickTime Player.

Doing a quick Google now reveals lots of people have encountered this problem and others have come to the same conclusion as I, e.g. [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2382398?tstart=0).

Other people's suggestions all seem to resort to GUI scripting, which I share your feelings about.

Sorry this isn't the answer you were hoping for.